# Error while using bluebird with ncp

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I use the following code which is working OK

```
var ncp =  require('ncp').ncp;

function load(folderPath) {
    ncp.limit = 16;
    var path = require('path');
    var localPath = path.join(__dirname, '../pl');
    ncp(folderPath, localPath, {dereference: false}, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return console.error(err);
        }
        console.log('done to save the files!');
    });
};
```

I want to use promise instead of callback but when using the following I got error

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var ncp = Promise.promisifyAll(require('ncp').ncp);

function load(folderPath) {
    ncp.limit = 16;
    var localPath = path.join(__dirname, '../pl');
    ncp(folderPath, localPath, {dereference: false})
        .then(function (result) {
            console.log('done to save the files!');
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.err(err);
        });
};
```

The error is :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

Comment: Try using `promisify` instead of `promisifyAll` (though I'm not sure how the `limit` property will work)

Comment: @Bergi - this is working please put is answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Promise.promisifyAll()` is used to promisify *objects*. It will iterate the object and promisify all of the function properties on that object.

However, `ncp` is a function itself, it doesn't have properties, so `promisifyAll()` won't do. You're looking for `promisify()` which takes a function as an argument, and returns a promisified function.

So all you need to do is change

```
var ncp = Promise.promisifyAll(require('ncp').ncp);
```

to

```
var ncp = Promise.promisify(require('ncp').ncp);
```